# Reorder data in SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have database filled with data from which i populate `recyclerview`. When user starts working on one of the `recyclerview` items I moved it on the top by `notifyItemMoved()` so user doesn't have to scroll down if he wants to input data, delete, manage etc. But of course when app is closed and opened up again item is returned to its original position so its not on the top anymore as I didn't save the last position. So my question is, I didn't find the answer, how can I reorder data inside database so next time when `recyclerview` is populated by data starts with last worked item or is there another better way for that?
I tried to update `id` from database but that didn't help same scenario happens items is on its first position. Thanks

Comment: Hate when got downvote without explanation!! If you know something then please share, close the question if it is duplicated but provide explanation.

Comment: Oh come on the obvious solution is to add column `modifyAt` and put the current time ther when user "starts working" with item.. Order by this column descent... That's what we call programming

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to create a column in the database with position, and update it on items changed.

Comment: @kara4a yeah, it's obvious way and he didn't even show what had he tried already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Introduce a column that will be used for ordering, let's call it `position`.
2. When the user is done managing records, update all rows according to their position in the dataset.
3. When loading data for the next user session, use `ORDER BY` to sort the entries according to `position` value.

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation. Like my brain was blocked I couldn't figure that out.